# Rate of Change Problem

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

> Bob can drive *m* miles in *h* hours. How long will it take him to drive *h* miles?

I came up with two concrete examples. Suppose he drove 6 miles in 1 hour. Then to drive 1 mile, it will take him a sixth of the time.

Now if he drove 6 miles in 2 hours, to drive 2 miles it would take him 1/3 of that time.

However, the answer book says that the answer is $h^2/m$. I can see how they arrive at this answer $(m/h*x = m$ and solve for $x)$, but is my first reasoning wrong? In that case it would have simply been $h/m$.

Comment: You have $\frac{m}{h}*x=m$ when you should have $\frac{m}{h}*x=h$.

Comment: Note that 1/3 of the time is 2/3 hours (=$2^2/6$)

Comment: @Peter 2/3rds is the amount of time in total. Would have been 80 minutes, not 40.

Comment: If it takes 120 minutes to drive 6 miles, then at the same speed it would take 20 minutes to drive 1 mile and 40 minutes (as I suggested) to drive 2 miles.

Comment: $6$ miles in $2$ hours is $3mph$.  To drive $2$miles and $3mph$ will be $\frac 23 hr$.  And $\frac 23 hr$ is $\frac 13 \times 2 hrs$.  And $\frac {2^2}{6} = \frac 46 = \frac 23$.  So *you* say it will take $\frac 23$ hrs, the answer book says it will take $\frac 23$ hr. And Peter says it will take $\frac 23 hr$ and I say it will take $\frac 23$ hr.  Let's have a party... I'll see you in $40$ minutes.

Comment: "In that case it would have simply been h/m."  Not quite.  You have that the rate of speed is $\frac mh$ and the time it takes to do $h$ miles is $\frac {distance}{rate} = \frac {h}{\frac mh} = \frac {h^2}m$

Answer (score 1):

Your first example’s answer *is* $\displaystyle\frac{h^2}m$ hour $\displaystyle=\frac{1^2}6$ hour.

Your second example is wrong though: a constant speed of $6$ miles in $2$ hours instead means $\frac66=1$ mile in $\frac26=\frac13$ hour, which means $2\times1=2$ miles in $2\times\frac13=\frac23$ hour; this again corresponds to $\displaystyle\frac{h^2}m=\frac{2^2}6=\frac23$ hour.

Comment: Yeah dude, but it doesnt work in the second example. Come on, man. Downvoted.

Comment: The given formula does work in example 2. The OP asked "is my first reasoning wrong?" which suggests that they offered multiple reasonings in which case "reasoning" could only mean "example". But thanks for pointing out that the OP rather meant to ask if their exampleS both are correct. Expanded the Answer to address this reading.